# How to unalias the default Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

After unaliasing my "default" project, Firebase still uses it:

```
> firebase use --unalias default
Removed alias default

Run firebase use --add to define a new project alias.

> firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'myproject0'...
```

My code base is deployed on multiple projects that I use as separate environments. I would like to explicitly specify the project for all my Firebase CLI commands to avoid messing with production or staging environments.
Is it not possible to unalias the default project?
Am I doing it wrong?

My .firebaserc is successfully updated:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "production": "myproject0",
    "test": "myproject-test"
  },
  "targets": {
    "myproject0": {
      "hosting": {
        "superadmin-webapp": [
          "superadmin-myproject0"
        ],
        "client-webapp": [
          "myproject"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the ".firebaserc" file contain in your project directory contain?  That's where the aliases go when you configure them.

Comment: The "default" key is successfully removed from .firebaserc. And I have inserted my new targets: "production": ..., "staging": ... And I have the same behaviour with "projects": {}

Comment: Oh but I see that my former default project is listed first in "targets", maybe that is where the CLI is picking a default-default project? I'll post my .firebaserc in the question.

Comment: Possibly, I don't know what it's doing here.  The CLI docs don't say anything about specifying a project on the command line, so you might be obliged to make sure you've added and used the correct project you want to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will set my test project as the default to avoid accidentally messing with production.